# Exception when I use Googleplayservices v71 with Xamarin Forms Maps v4.3

Tags: google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.forms, google-play-services, onesignal

When I want to show google Maps I'm getting a:

Java.Lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 'Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/dynamic/zza;'

It was working fine before I installed:

xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base 71.1610.0 and xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement 71.1620.0

I need these two plugins because Com.OneSignal requires them.

When I uninstall Com.Onesignal it also doesn't work, but when I also uninstall xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base and xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement again, I don't get the exception again and it shows the map. But then no notifications :(

I using Xamarin Forms 4.3.0.947036 and using a shell project.

Comment: Post an issue: https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Xamarin-SDK/issues

Comment: I've done that now, but dont think it's a OneSignal issue, more a googleplayservices issue.

Comment: As far as I know, you can't use 71.x and higher packages without migrating to AndroidX. You need to install and use OneSignal(which should be 3.3.0) to work with GooglePlayServices 60.x. Even if you try to migrate AndroidX, you will still have problems with this package.